# "Network Unreachable" via WiFi Client Bridge

Tags: networking, routing

I've been battling an issue for some time now, attempting to get my home lab environment working.

**Diagram displaying relevant parts of the network in question**
[image]

**The issue**

If I attempt to reach `10.0.10.1` (the IP of VLAN 10), or `10.0.10.2` (the IP of the device connected to Gi0/1 on the Cisco-switch) from either the computer on `10.0.0.10` or the laptop on `10.0.0.75`, I get a response from `10.0.0.3` (the Zyxel WiFi Bridge) with "Destination net unreachable".

This makes no sense to me. In my head, I'm attempting to reach a network outside of my current broadcast domain - so the next hop would logically be the gateway at `10.0.0.1`. Doing a traceroute, I can also confirm that is the case.

```
tracert 10.0.10.1

Tracing route to 10.0.10.1 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1
  2  10.0.0.3  reports: Destination net unreachable.

Trace complete.
```

`10.0.0.1` is on eth1 on the EdgeRouter 4. This interface also has `172.20.0.1/24` bound, acting as a gateway for that range as well. Furthermore, it has a static route added, which routes `10.0.10.0/24 via 172.20.0.2` (which is the Cisco L3 Switch).

So, what could possibly lead to the client device (the Zyxel  - which only serves to bring connectivity to the lab since I can't run cables there) to not understand how to route the traffic? Unfortunately, there's little to no settings for the Zyxel device.

One thing I've noted is that any  traffic I send from my PC, or from the EdgeRouter, to devices *behind* the Zyxel AP, result in ARP entries for those IP's with the *Zyxel* MAC Address. However, looking from the other side (so devices behind the Zyxel AP and back), it seems to behave as expected (with the correct mac addresses being stored in the arp table). My conclusion is simply that the Zyxel device seems to proxy ARP, which I don't think (but please correct me if I'm wrong) should really break anything.

Am I right in guessing that the Zyxel is doing something weird here - and that the configuration as described/illustrated should, in theory, work - or am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Still haven't solved the original issue, but I have got the traffic working by instead establishing a GRE tunnel between the EdgeRouter and the Cisco Switch. This way, for the Zyxel device, the traffic is just 172.20.0.1 -> 172.20.0.2 which was always working - but encapsulated is the tunnel traffic (192.168.200.1 -> 192.168.200.2). This solves the use case - but I'm still curious why the Zyxel bridge can't deal with this without the workaround.

Comment: You have the Zyxel WAP connected to the Cisco with a 10.0.0.0/24 subnet, however, the cisco has no interface with that subnet. 10.0.1.0/24 yes, but not 10.0.0.0/24. Looking at it, both WiFi devices need to be in the 172.20.0.0/24 network if that is what interface they are connected to. That will mean the 10.0.0.74 pc will also have to be in that subnet.

Comment: @Bib The Zyxel WAP is connected over WiFi to the EdgeRouter on the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet - whereas the uplink on the Cisco (which is cabled to the Zyxel WAP) is a router port at `172.20.0.2`. Traffic from my device (for example `10.0.0.74`) should go to its default GW, which has a route saying "10.0.10.0/24, next hop 172.20.0.2" - no? Why does the Zyxel WAP do anything here other than shuffle traffic (since it's in client mode, it of course doesn't route, but the route exists in the actual routers)

Comment: sorry, but this is as clear as mud. Why are you connecting the Zyxel, which has an IP address of 10.0.0.3 to the cisco router which has an IP address of 172.20.0.2? You are also showing the Ubiquiti router as having both sunbets off the same port.

Comment: @Bib I think you're misunderstanding. The Zyxel WAP is in client bridge mode. It aims to act as a "wireless cable", so it connects the EdgeRouter to the Cisco L3 Switch router port (so a router->router connection). It merely provides connectivity to the switch. As for the Ubi Router, it does have two subnets off the same port. The port has two IP's bound to it. That part works without issue and is what results in the Cisco router port being reachable at all, since it's off a different subnet.